# Create 4 level nested object aggregate output from a linear mongo collection

Tags: mongodb

I have following schema

```
{
        question: String,
        answer: Number,
        option1: String,
        option2: String,
        option3: String,
        option4: String,
        subject: String,
        chapter: String,
        topic: String,
        subtopic: String,
        tags: { type: Array, default: [] },
        difficulty: String,
        media: { type: String, default: "" }
}
```

I want to create a index from this question schema, where a unique entry in index can be identified by tuple (subject, chapter, topic, subtopic)

```
{
    "subject": {
        "chapter": {
            "topic": ["subtopics"],
            "topic": ["subtopics"],
        },
        "chapter": {
            "topic": ["subtopics"],
            "topic": ["subtopics"],
        },
    },
    "subject": {
        "chapter": {
            "topic": ["subtopics"],
            "topic": ["subtopics"],
        },
        "chapter": {
            "topic": ["subtopics"],
            "topic": ["subtopics"],
        },
    },
}
```

To achieve above result I have been trying some aggregations and so far I am able to get upto

```
{
    "subject": ["chapters"],
    "subject": ["chapters"],
    "subject": ["chapters"],
    "subject": ["chapters"],
}
```

using following pipeline in mongoose

```
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$subject",
                    chapters: { $push: "$chapter" }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    chapters: { $push: { "k": "$_id", "v": "$chapters" } }
                }
            },
            {
                $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$chapters" } }
            }
```

When I tried to extend my above logic to include topic ans subtopics using

```
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$subject",
                    chapters: { $push: { "k": "$chapter", "v": { topic: "$topic", subtopic: "$subtopic" } } }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    chapters: { $push: { "k": "$_id", "v": { "$arrayToObject": "$chapters" } } }
                }
            },
            {
                $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$chapters" } }
            }
```

I get following output

```
{
    "subject": {
        "chapter": {
            "topic": "value",
            "subtopic": "value"
        },
        "chapter": {
            "topic": "value",
            "subtopic": "value"
        },
    },
    "subject": {
        "chapter": {
            "topic": "value",
            "subtopic": "value"
        },
        "chapter": {
            "topic": "value",
            "subtopic": "value"
        },
    },
}
```

[image: Current Output]

**Problem is that chapter is a object of last topic and subtopic only** I know where I am making mistake but I don;t know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you please give us a couple of actual sample documents, that way it would be easy to answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregation that mainly utilizes [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/), the data restructuring is not so elegant though:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : { 
                    "subject" : "$subject", 
                    "chapter" : "$chapter", 
                    "topic" : "$topic"
                }, 
                "topics" : { 
                    "$push" : "$subtopic"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "topic" : { 
                    "k" : "$_id.topic", 
                    "v" : "$topics"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : { 
                    "subject" : "$_id.subject", 
                    "chapter" : "$_id.chapter"
                }, 
                "topics" : { 
                    "$push" : "$topic"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "topics" : { 
                    "$arrayToObject" : "$topics"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "chapters" : [
                    { 
                        "k" : "$_id.chapter", 
                        "v" : "$topics"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "chapters" : { 
                    "$arrayToObject" : "$chapters"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : null, 
                "subject" : { 
                    "$push" : { 
                        "k" : "$_id.subject", 
                        "v" : "$chapters"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "final" : { 
                    "$arrayToObject" : "$subject"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$replaceRoot" : { 
                "newRoot" : "$final"
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, with little changes particular to my use case I was able to use your pipeline. Notably by using `$addToSet` and `$setDifference` in subtopics :)

Comment: Also by not using pipeline and using a custom format function later on projected document I was able to generate same result.. I wonder which approach would be optimum? Any heads up in this direction?